# How to get Around MS Access Column Number Limitation: Too Many Fields Defined

Tags: ms-access, vba

I inherited an MS Access database that is very poorly designed.  I am working on redesign but in the meantime I need to provide enhancements to this current version.  Because of varying datatype issues I have had to create many alter table queries to force fields into the proper datatypes.  Long story short, I run into a "Too Many Fields Defined" error message from time to time while I am running the alter table/alter column queries.  I've read up on it and found that the internal MS Access Column count increases whenever you run an alter column query.  I am able to solve this issue by hitting the Compact and Repair button.  However when my end users are running the program I don't want them to have to do this.  Is there a way to either programmatically Compact and Repair (Checking the Compact on Close option doesn't seem to work) with VBA?  Or can I somehow reset the internal table column count with VBA?

Comment: "Checking the Compact on Close option doesn't seem to work." That's odd. Do the users have the tables or just a front-end?

Comment: You should continue your redesign until the application, at runtime, doesn't have to alter the fields.

Comment: Please provide the necessary code for us to replicate the issue, compact on close should just work. See [this DBA question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193214/128211) about programatically compacting, you can only compact if the database is closed.

Comment: It is clear that you are redesigning the database, but in the mean time I bet there is likely an alternative solution to continuously altering column types.   It sounds like that was something you added after the fact, so could you not just change the queries or code to massage (i.e. reformat, refactor, convert) data to proper types without changing the underlying table columns?

Comment: @C Perkins I did add this after the fact, but I'm not sure what you mean by massaging the data.  The reason I added so many alter column statements was because the data is being uploaded from many different client files.  When the files are imported they don't always come in with consistent datatypes, thus after a user imports a client file, I have a sub procedure run alter column statements to massage the data as you say

Comment: @Wazz The database is not split currently.  I should probably split it for other reasons but I don't think that would solve the issue of the column count being affected each time I run an alter column statement (which I have to do for 80+ columns in 3 tables)

Comment: @Chuck0185 you're right, the question was tangential. i should have skipped it.

Comment: A better approach would be: have production tables with the structure you want. When you import data, you import it into (or as) temp tables, and from there you run an insert into the production tables.

Comment: @Chuck0185  Andre mentioned one technique of what I meant about massaging the data.  Essentially use temp tables and/or import queries which change the data BEFORE inserting into the final table.  There are various VBA functions (and you can write your own) that can be used to change data into different types, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can only compact a closed database - which means your code has to run in a separate database - so you have to split the front end off, run the compact routine for the backend db and then attach the tables programatically. Compacting has to be done in DAO so you need a reference to that

```
Sub CompactDatabaseRoutine()
Dim dbe As DBEngine
Dim source As String
Dim dest As String

Set dbe = DBEngine
source = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Sales2010.mdb"
dest = "C:\Documents and Settings\user\tempSales2010.mdb"

dbe.CompactDatabase source, dest
If Dir(dest) <> "" Then
Kill source
Name dest As source
End If


End Sub
```